# How to extract 2d year from text in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, extract

I tried to extract birthyear and deathyear from a short text looking like that in a column in a Pandas DataFrame :

```
firstname lastname (1937-2015)
```

I used this code to get the first year:

```
data = re.findall(r'\d+', txt)
if len(data) > 0 :
    data = float(data[0])
    if data >= 1800 and data <= 2021 :
        return data
return None
```

but I can't extract the second year from the text.
When I change `data[0]` into `data[1]` for example, I have an error message "list index out of range"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define 2 capture groups and check them

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'txt': ['firstname lastname (1937-2015)', 'firstname lastname (1780-1820)',
             'firstname lastname (1945-?)', 'firstname lastname (1980-2022)']})

df[['birth', 'death']] = df['txt'].str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+|\?)').replace({'?': None}).astype(float). \
    applymap(lambda x: x if 1800 <= x <= 2021 else None)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                              txt   birth   death
0  firstname lastname (1937-2015)  1937.0  2015.0
1  firstname lastname (1780-1820)     NaN  1820.0
2     firstname lastname (1945-?)  1945.0     NaN
3  firstname lastname (1980-2022)  1980.0     NaN
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. It worked very well. I have now discovered errors because some rows have only one year (only the birth year) and others have a special characters instead of the year (like 1945-?). How can I manage that ? Do I need to extract in 2 different sequences ? On with : r'(\d+)-* and the other one with : r'.*-(\d{4})' ?

Comment: You can process variants `(1937-2015)` and `(1945-?)` in one expression like `r'(\d+)-(\d+|\?)'` - see updated code

Answer (score 2):

A generic regex solution to extract the second year (from 1800 to 2099) in Pandas using `Series.str.extract` you can leverage

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['firstname lastname (1937-2015)']})
yr = r'(?:1[89][0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9]|202[01])'
df['second_year'] = df['col'].str.extract(fr'(?s)(?<!\d){yr}(?!\d).*?({yr})(?!\d)')
# => df['second_year']
#   0    2015
#   Name: second_year, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mPyNY4/5). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `.` now matches across lines
- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand numeric boundary
- `(?:1[89][0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9]|202[01])` - from 1800 to 2021
- `(?!\d)` - a right hand numeric boundary
- `.*?` - any text, as few chars as possible
- `(1[89][0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9]|202[01])` - Group 1 (the actual return result of `Series.str.extract`): 1800 to 2021
- `(?!\d)` -  a right hand numeric boundary

In this concrete case, a simple

```py
df['second_year'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'.*-(\d{4})')
```

will be enough: any text (as many chars other than line break chars as possible) and then a `-` and four digits captured into Group 1.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mPyNY4/5).

Comment: Hi, big thanks for your help :) I just found out some raws had only one date (ex : 1937) and others had a special character (ex : 1937-?). Would something like : .str.extract(r'(\d+)-) could work on the first part ?

Comment: @Gwen Just use `df['second_year'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'.*\b(\d{4})')`. I see you are not really interested in validation here.

Comment: Sorry, validation ?

Comment: @Gwen You are validating the year with `if data >= 1800 and data <= 2021`.

Comment: Since  yesterday, and read your response, I changed my approach of the dataset and I first cleaned it by excluding every year older than 1800 and stopping at 2021 on the other end. So I don't need the validation part anymore and I can use the str.extract only, which make my code cleaner I think

Comment: @Gwen Ok, that is fine. I do not know how you excluded the  the years, but just in case, if you used a regex I hope it is some kind of `r'\b\d{4}\b'`, `r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)'`, etc.

Comment: yes it is :) Thanks again for your help Wiktor

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expression to find the year from and to sub phrase then split it and index the second year.  you can use this in a dataframe apply for assignment to a column

```
txt="firstname lastname (1937-2015)"
pattern='(\d{4}\-\d{4})+'

matches=re.findall(pattern,txt)
print(matches[0].split('-')[1])
```

output

```
2015
```